# Change image source when resizing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have images in my page and if resulution of my page less than 768px my img src must change with `data-tablet` and if resulution of my page less than 480px my img src must change with `data-mobil` or if my resulution bigger than 768px img src must change with `data-web` or if my resulution bigger than 480 it must change with `data-tablet` I wrote some code for it but I guess there is something wrong with condition or syntax

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
     $(".box img").each(function(){
       var getWeb = $(this).parents(".box").find("img").attr("data-web");
       var getTablet = $(this).parents(".box").find("img").attr("data-tablet");
       var getMobil = $(this).parents(".box").find("img").attr("data-mobil");
       
   if ($(window).width() < 768) {
         $(this).attr("data-src",getTablet);
      }else if ($(window).width() < 480){
        $(this).attr("data-src",getMobil);
      }else if ($(window).width() > 480){
           $(this).attr("data-src",getTablet);
       }else if($(window).width() > 768)
      {
        $(this).attr("data-src",getWeb);
      }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.box{
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}
.box img{
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  
 <div class="box">
    <img data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/18/21/34/cyprus-1990939_960_720.jpg" data-web="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/18/21/34/cyprus-1990939_960_720.jpg" data-tablet="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/31/09/30/raspberry-2023404_960_720.jpg" data-mobil="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/20/15/12/ring-nebula-1995076_960_720.jpg" class="lazyload" />
  </div>
  
    
  <div class="box">
    <img data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/20/15/06/orange-1995056_960_720.jpg" data-web="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/20/15/06/orange-1995056_960_720.jpg" data-tablet="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/29/12/46/apple-379373_960_720.jpg" data-mobil="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/21/00/29/fruit-1213041_960_720.jpg" class="lazyload" />
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/2.0.7/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

by the way just these code works

```
else if ($(window).width() > 480){
           $(this).attr("data-src",getTablet);
       }
```

[and click to see project on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/jypEXE)

Comment: Why not just a pure css solution with media queries(try resizing the html result) : https://jsfiddle.net/45bgz00s/1/

Comment: @Hackerman it will be dynamic

Comment: Mmmm...your code doesn't seems to be optimal; that's why media queries where created in the first place...nevermind....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your code inside a function and calling it when document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

checksize();

 function checksize(){
  $(".box img").each(function(){
    var getWeb = $(this).parents(".box").find("img").attr("data-web");
    var getTablet = $(this).parents(".box").find("img").attr("data-tablet");
    var getMobil = $(this).parents(".box").find("img").attr("data-mobil");

    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $(this).attr("data-src",getTablet);
    }else if ($(window).width() < 480){
     $(this).attr("data-src",getMobil);
    }else if ($(window).width() > 480){
       $(this).attr("data-src",getTablet);
     }else if($(window).width() > 768)
    {
     $(this).attr("data-src",getWeb);
    }
   });
 }

});
```

Comment: I guess problem is not about the function problem is about the my js code

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your check for window width and run your code on the resize event

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
  [your code]
};
```

Comment: but it at the same time for devices

Comment: @recruit_man so you just want the code to fire when the page loads not on resize of the browser window?